# Use Visual Studio Lightswitch to generate a hashed password and store it in database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-lightswitch

I use Lightswitch as a frontend to a SQL Server database which powers a webshop (ASP.NET).

I now want to be able to give customers new passwords (also SHA256 encoded) using Lightswitch.

There is a customers table with a field `Password`. Is there a way to have a button an TextBox on my customers Screen that adds functionality to generate a SHA256 (and then Base64) encoded Password?

At the moment I have an aspx page that generates the encoded password when a user registers with the shop:

```
Dim inputBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)
Dim algorithm As HashAlgorithm = New SHA256Managed
Dim outputBytes As Byte() = algorithm.ComputeHash(inputBytes)
Dim hashedPassword As String = Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes)
```

Is there a way to achieve that in Lightswitch?

Comment: @Kamiccolo, I don't know why your edit was approved, but please don't put tags in the body. Tags belong in the tag section, unless you are on the meta.

Comment: @gunr2171 sorry. Lack of sleep. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: You're using a HTML Client? There are multiple jQuery plugins that can do hashing and Base64. Use the type="password" attribute for your input field.